# How do I split a long string into "wrapped" strings?

Tags: delphi, string

How to perform this in Delphi?

I have a very long string.
I need to wrap sting every 5 letters and add a dot in the end of wrapped string.

Example string:

```
ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

Result:

```
sssss. 
sssss. 
sssss. 
sssss.
```

Comment: Formatted question for clarity on the newline. (As soon as someone reviews and accepts my edit!)

Answer (score 7):

Your teacher probably wants you to learn enough pascal to write something like this:

```
 loop through the characters in the string
   get a character from the string and add it to another string
   check if five letters have gone by, and if so, 
      add a dot and a carriage-return-and-linefeed character.
 end loop
```

Comment: +1 for answering a homework question correctly. (A question that asks how to do something basic without posting the code they've tried which doesn't work.) Good job, @Warren!

Answer (score 4):

```
uses SysUtils;

Result := WrapText(s, '.'^M^J, [], 5);
```

But be careful of this note from [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.WrapText):

> WrapText does not insert a break into an embedded quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following:

```
while Length(s) > 0 do
begin
  Result := Result + '. ' + Copy(s, ...);
  Delete(s, ...);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one only works in recent Delphi's:

```
  for c in s do
  begin
    Write(c);
    if i mod maxSize=maxSize-1 then
      WriteLn('.');
    inc(i);
  end;
```

Iterate through all characters

```
  for i := 1 to length(s) do
  begin
    Write(s[i]);
    if i mod maxSize=0 then
      WriteLn('.');
  end;
```

Copy chunks

```
  for i := 0 to length(s) div maxSize do
    WriteLn(Copy(s,1+i*maxSize,maxSize),'.');
```